# Benchmarking Functions for Computing Average RGB Value of Images

Tags: python

I implemented computation of average RGB value of a Python Imaging Library image in 2 ways:

## 1 - using lists

```
def getAverageRGB(image):
  """
  Given PIL Image, return average value of color as (r, g, b)
  """
  # no. of pixels in image
  npixels = image.size[0]*image.size[1]
  # get colors as [(cnt1, (r1, g1, b1)), ...]
  cols = image.getcolors(npixels)
  # get [(c1*r1, c1*g1, c1*g2),...]
  sumRGB = [(x[0]*x[1][0], x[0]*x[1][1], x[0]*x[1][2]) for x in cols] 
  # calculate (sum(ci*ri)/np, sum(ci*gi)/np, sum(ci*bi)/np)
  # the zip gives us [(c1*r1, c2*r2, ..), (c1*g1, c1*g2,...)...]
  avg = tuple([sum(x)/npixels for x in zip(*sumRGB)])
  return avg
```

## 2 - using numpy

```
def getAverageRGBN(image):
  """
  Given PIL Image, return average value of color as (r, g, b)
  """
  # get image as numpy array
  im = np.array(image)
  # get shape
  w,h,d = im.shape
  # change shape
  im.shape = (w*h, d)
  # get average
  return tuple(np.average(im, axis=0))
```

I was surprised to find that #1 runs about 20% faster than #2.

Am I using numpy correctly? Is there a better way to implement the average computation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surprising indeed.

You may want to use:

```
tuple(im.mean(axis=0))
```

to compute your mean `(r,g,b)`, but I doubt it's gonna improve things a lot. Have you tried to profile `getAverageRGBN` and find the bottleneck?

Comment: this is probably about memory reallocating, maybe np.asarray(image) or np.array(image.getdata(), np.uint8) would do better

Comment: I see a definite improvement with `mean`. I haven't done much profiling in Python - any suggestions?

Comment: @M-V You have some [profilers](http://docs.python.org/library/profile.html) coming with Python, you could also install some thrid-party packages like [`line_profiler`](http://packages.python.org/line_profiler/): this latter is quite nice.

Answer (score 0):

One-liner w/o changing dimension or writing getAverageRGBN:

```
np.array(image).mean(axis=(0,1))
```

Again, it might not improve any performance.

Answer (score 0):

In PIL or Pillow, in Python 3.4+:

```
from statistics import mean
average_color = [mean(image.getdata(band)) for band in range(3)]
```